# How to set background-color in CSS for a specific HTML element without affecting child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-color

I am trying to set the background color property of an HTML element while maintaining the default background for its specific child elements. Consider a simplified scenario here:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 500px;
}

.sidebar {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width:50px;
  background: blue;
}

.sidebar2 {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width:50px;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}

.input, .output {
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="input">
      <div class="nestedinput">
        <p>
        Input content
        </p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="output">
      <p>
      Output content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This compiles to the following UI:
[image]

I want to be able to set the background for the outermost `container` element with the green border **without** over-riding the background for the `input`, `output` or the blue sidebar that you see (and their nested children as well). I understand that I can set `background-color` for the `input`, `output` elements explicitly but I can not do that. I want them to be set to `transparent` and inherit whatever is the base background.
I need to this because the content for the `input` and `output` elements are coming from an `iframe` element stacked underneath this entire layer in the DOM and we'd want these `input` and `output` stub elements to have the same CSS background etc. that is coming straight from the iframe content.

I wish to achieve an output like the following:
[image]

Note that this is a simplified example where I just have 2 elements i.e. `input` and `output` (and their nested children) that don't have to have their background set. I'd want their background to remain `transparent`.

I tried playing around with the `:not` CSS selector like so (and several variations) of it:

```
.container :not(.input > *) {
  background: grey;
}
```

But it always seems to be setting the background for the whole thing.

Comment: it is not setting the background for all elements. If you set the background transparent for input elements, then obviously the background of the container background will show up through the transparent input elements. You can test that by setting background for container to grey and the inputs to white.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'base background'? Is it the background color of the parent of container or...

Comment: @AHaworth, may be I should clarify that in the question. The scenario here is that the contents for the `input` and `output` containers are coming from an `iframe` element that is at the bottom of the DOM. So, the `input` and `output` elements are stubs that are defined on top with a `transparent` background. That way, the content from the `iframe` shows up with whatever CSS and background it has. And that background could be anything which is why it is important for the `input` and `output` elements to be `transparent`. Does that help?

Comment: @Nolan, I added some clarification to my question. See my comment above.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer. Basically you want 'holes' in the grey background wherever the input and output are. Is there other stuff under the grey background which also has to disapear or it is just the grey?

Comment: I can only think of a way of doing this using Javascript - is that acceptable?

Comment: That is absolutely correct @AHaworth. I'd ideally want to be able to do this in CSS. Please do share your thoughts on how to do this in Javascript. Would love to get some ideas. Thanks!